# Reduce quality in imagepng without save the file

Tags: php, image

I use this code in `images.php` to show the images :

```
imagepng($out);
```

and if i want to reduce the images quality for thumbnails i tried this code :

```
imagepng($out,$filename,$quality);
```

i want to know how to reduce image quality without saving.

Comment: thanks , that's work

Comment: The 'quality' in `imagepng()` refers to the 'Compression level' of the file that is produced. It does not literaly affect image quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function resize_image($file, $w, $h, $crop=false) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
    $r = $width / $height;
    if ($crop) {
        if ($width > $height) {
            $width = ceil($width-($width*abs($r-$w/$h)));
        } else {
            $height = ceil($height-($height*abs($r-$w/$h)));
        }
        $newwidth = $w;
        $newheight = $h;
    } else {
        if ($w/$h > $r) {
            $newwidth = $h*$r;
            $newheight = $h;
        } else {
            $newheight = $w/$r;
            $newwidth = $w;
        }
    }

    //Get file extension
    $exploding = explode(".",$file);
    $ext = end($exploding);

    switch($ext){
        case "png":
            $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
        break;
        case "jpeg":
        case "jpg":
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
        break;
        case "gif":
            $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
        break;
        default:
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
        break;
    }

    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    return $dst;
}

$filename = "/var/www/images/mynormalimage.png";
$resizedFilename = "/var/www/images/myresizedimage.png";

// resize the image with 300x300
$imgData = resize_image($filename, 300, 300);
// save the image on the given filename
imagepng($imgData, $resizedFilename);
// or according to the original format, use another method
// imagejpeg($imgData, $resizedFilename);
// imagegif($imgData, $resizedFilename);
```

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/197/how-to-resize-an-image-and-reduce-quality-in-php-without-imagick`enter code here`

Comment: // Get the data from a png file
$imageData = resize_image("myfolder/myfile.png",500,500);
// Give a name to your file with the full patj
$filepath = "myfolder/myresizedimage.png";
$quality = 0;

imagepng($imageData,$filepath,$quality);